# how would i add more video sources to my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

> i have 5 different videos and i want them to add more then one source
>   to them so that they can play in more browsers but im not sure on how
>   to make it so you can do that.  here is what my javascript looks like
>   it is pretty repetitive

```
function addVideo1() {
  var changeStuff = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    changeStuff.src = "video/demoreel.mp4";

}

function addVideo2() {
 var changeStuff = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    changeStuff.src = "video/video1.mp4";
}

function addVideo3() {
    var changeStuff = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    changeStuff.src = "video/video2.mp4";
}

function addVideo4() {
    var changeStuff = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    changeStuff.src = "video/video3.mp4";

}

function addVideo5() {
    var changeStuff = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    changeStuff.src = "video/video4.mp4";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/fPKK8/), it should do what you want.

**ARGH!** I did it in jQuery, sorry. I wasn't paying attention. Ok, I went back and did it in plain ol' javascript.

**HTML**

```
<div id="video"><video></video></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-video="video1.mp4">Video 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-video="video2.mp4">Video 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-video="video3.mp4">Video 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i ++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var video = this.dataset["video"];
        var source = document.createElement("source");
        source.src = video;
        var container = document.getElementById("video");
        var v = container.firstChild;
        v.innerHTML = "";
        v.appendChild(source);
    });
}
```

**CSS**

Not necessary, just to "prettify" it a bit

```
html { padding: 10px; }
#container { width: 450px; }
#video { width: 320px; height: 240px; border: 3px solid #CCC; }
ul { margin: 10px 0; width: 320px; padding: 0; }
ul li { display: inline; margin: 0 10px 0 0; padding: 0;  }
```

Comment: i didnt mention that i have five different buttons and when you click on the button the video pops up and i have one video tag so that when you click on them it goes in that spot

Answer (score 1):

To create multiple sources, you need to have source elements inside the video tag rather than using the video's source attribute.  Use:

```
sourceElement=document.createElement("source")
sourceElement.source=someSource
sourceElement.type=someType
changeStuff.appendChild(sourceElement)
```

Comment: this what i have in my html ' <video id="myVideo" source src="video/demoreel.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls autoplay></video>
    <div>
     <a href="#" onClick="addVideo1()">Demo Reel</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="addVideo2()">Video1</a>
  <a href="#" onClick="addVideo3()">Video2</a>
  <a href="#" onClick="addVideo4()">Video3</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="addVideo5()">Video4</a> 
 </div>'

Comment: and javascript now function addVideo1() {
sourceElement=document.createElement("source")
sourceElement.source= "video/demoreel.ogv"
sourceElement.type="video/ogv"
changeStuff.appendChild(sourceElement)
}

Comment: I'm not sure why, I'm not able to test right now (on my phone), if your browser has firebug or some other developer tools, can you inspect the video element after addVideo1 is called and post the code?

Comment: yea it just says {
sourceElement=document.createElement("source")
sourceElement.source= "video/demoreel.ogv"
sourceElement.type="video/ogv"
changeStuff.appendChild(sourceElement)
}

Comment: I mean the code for the video element after the JavaScript has modified it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (untested, typed on mobile).

```
function addSource(id,type,path) {

    var vid=document.getElementById(id);
    vid.innerHTML+='<source src="'+path+'" type="'+type+'">';
}
```